# Jquery to resize divs on page load/resize

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have the following JQuery that is called whenever the window is resized or on first load. I have some issues with it that it does not seem to work as expected on first load. Could someone please tell me what is malfunctioning?

## JQuery (1.8.3)

```
function setContentHeight() {
    var height = $(document).height();
    $('#content, #content > div:first-child').height(height - 242);
    $('#content-text-description').height(height - 280);
}

$(window).resize(function(e) {
    setContentHeight();
});

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    setContentHeight();
});
```

## HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="banner"></div> <!-- Header -->
        <div id="navi"></div> <!-- Navigation Pane -->
        <div id="content"> <!-- Content loaded with include -->
            <div id="home"> <!-- Start of content -->
                <div id="content-text-description"></div> <!-- container for custom scroller -->
            </div>
        <div id="footer"></div> <!-- Footer -->
    </div>
</body>
```

## CSS

```
body {
   margin:0;
   font-family:"Century Gothic";
   line-height:30px;
}

#container {
    width:1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#banner {
    width:1024px;
}

#content {
    width:1024px;           
    height:470px;
    z-index:98;
    float:left; 
    top:-7px;   
    overflow:hidden;
}

#footer {
    text-align:center;
    background:#59585D;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    width:1024px;
    height:30px;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#ffffff;
}

#content-text-description {
    padding-top:20px;
    display:block;
    width:800px;
    z-index:3;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

As far as I know, the JQuery bit should function as expected by resizing the requested divs when the document is loaded or window resized, but it is not.

Is it something I'm doing wrong or is what I'm trying to achieve not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by playing with the code some more...

Simple really.

```
var height = $(document).height();
```

should change to:

```
var height = $(window).height();
```

Answer (score 0):

Cdocument.ready event is too early to check height, use document.load event instead

$(window).resize(function(e) {
setContentHeight() ;
});

$(document).load(function(e) {
setContentHeight() ;
});

Reason is document.load event is fired soon after entire dom has been downloaded. But at that tme rendering has not happened, css may not be applied, images not loaded, etc. Therefore height will not be correct.

But load event fired after everything has been downloaded and styles are applied, so you should get a correct height.

Anyhow this is not something you should do with a script, instead do it with styling.